# static files in springboot project deployed to an external Tomcat with WAR

Tags: spring-boot, maven, tomcat, war, static-files

I'm new to Spring and Springboot, I'm just trying an easy thing I can't sort out:
As per the title, I want to put in a project some static files, then package the project with maven as war and deploy it to an existing Tomcat.
I'm using Springboot 2.7.8, Java 17 and Tomcat 8.5.47

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-01</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo-01</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and this is my application class:

```
package com.example.demo01;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo01Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Demo01Application.class);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo01Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

then I've put an "Hello World" index.html under src/main/resources/static
and finally I've run

```
mvn clean package
```

and I've got a war file like this:

```
├───META-INF
└───WEB-INF
    ├───classes
    │   │   application.properties
    │   │
    │   ├───com
    │   │   └───example
    │   │       └───demo01
    │   │               Demo01Application.class
    │   │
    │   └───static
    │           index.html
    │
    └───lib
            jackson-annotations-2.13.4.jar
            jackson-core-2.13.4.jar
            jackson-databind-2.13.4.2.jar
            jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.13.4.jar
            jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.4.jar
            jackson-module-parameter-names-2.13.4.jar
            jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
            jul-to-slf4j-1.7.36.jar
            log4j-api-2.17.2.jar
            log4j-to-slf4j-2.17.2.jar
            logback-classic-1.2.11.jar
            logback-core-1.2.11.jar
            slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar
            snakeyaml-1.30.jar
            spring-aop-5.3.25.jar
            spring-beans-5.3.25.jar
            spring-boot-2.7.8.jar
            spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.8.jar
            spring-boot-starter-2.7.8.jar
            spring-boot-starter-json-2.7.8.jar
            spring-boot-starter-logging-2.7.8.jar
            spring-boot-starter-web-2.7.8.jar
            spring-context-5.3.25.jar
            spring-core-5.3.25.jar
            spring-expression-5.3.25.jar
            spring-jcl-5.3.25.jar
            spring-web-5.3.25.jar
            spring-webmvc-5.3.25.jar
```

As you can see, th index.html is under WEB-INF\classes\static
Is it supposed to be served by tomcat from that location?!

Anyway: I've deployed the war file to Tomcat, and when I point my browser to http://localhost/demo-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT I get a sad 404

What an I missing ?

**EDIT:**
I've found the cause of my problem (thanks to @khmarbaise who pointed me in the right direction): since the external Tomcat instance (8.5.47) is using Java 8, having instructed Spring Boot to make the package compliant with Java 17, with these directive in my pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
```

created the problem.

It was sufficient to remove these three lines, and now everything works fine.

Comment: First spring boot 2.7.8 uses `<tomcat.version>9.0.71</tomcat.version>` as version for tomcat. That means you explictily use a different version to deploy the WAR to which is not related to the Spring Boot version. Is it necessary to use an external Tomcat? Why not using spring boot jar ? Furthermore I expect that the name of the war file: `demo-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` which means the context path is also named that way. You can check that in Tomcat..

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you for your comment. I'm not sure what you mean about Tomcat version... Yes, it is necessary I use that external Tomcat. Isn't it possible? Do I have to explicitly specifiy the version somewhere?
For the name you are right: the context is actually demo-01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, and that's what I try to point to in my browser. I've edited the question.

Comment: Ok you say you need an external Tomcat? I would ask why ... Ok.. the version where spring boot is using itself while running is a complete different versions (9.0.X vs. 8.5.X) maybe there could be some differences..If the context is different than you have to use that context in the usage of your browser... have you installed the tomcat manager to look where it's really installed ??

Comment: I need to use an external Tomcat because I'm bound to external constraint (a Tomcat instance already in place, impossibility to open other ports, etc.). Anyway, you are right, there are differences, and they were the cause of my problem. BTW, I've solved my problem, I'm going to edit my question to explain how.